# Cache should refresh on each day CacheItemPolicy

Tags: c#, caching

I am caching some list of objects using CacheItemPolic like below:

```
var getReviewKey = _configurationRepository.GetConfigurationValue("getReviewListKey");
            var reviewList = _cachingService.Retrieve<ReviewContentDto>(getReviewKey);
            var cachepolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            cachepolicy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new HostFileChangeMonitor(new List<string> { _configurationRepository.GetConfigurationValue("getReviewListMonitorFile") }));            
            if(reviewList==null)
            {
                reviewList = _menuService.GetReviewDetails();
                _cachingService.Remove(getReviewKey);
                _cachingService.Store(getReviewKey, reviewList);
            }
```

I want to refresh this cache on each day. That means, Cache should clear on each day morning, then get updated data from menuservice, then store into cache.

Now If I change the monitor file, cache is cleared and get updated data from menuservice.

but I want to do this automatically on each day.

Please suggest option to achieve this.

Comment: Try setting the policy.AbsoluteExpiration =
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);